# How can I make extensions part of statement dynamic?

Tags: javascript, tin-can-api

There is one part of sending statements that has me stumped. In the first group of code I'm setting some variables that I then successfully use to send the statement. Everything works **except** when I try and do this for 'extension.'
I set variables for both parts of the extension but when I try to use it in the second group of code I cannot get it to work. I've tried escaping the quotes and lots of other combinations but nothing work. The console error message states, "Bad Request." How can I modify my extensions area in the bottom set of code so that it will work. Thank you.

```
//this happens when the user clicks the 'Find your English level' link
$("#findYourEnglishLevel").click(function () {
    window.open('https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/content', 'myWin', 'scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,top=50,left=50,width=1280,height=920');
    var name = localStorage.getItem("name");
    var email = localStorage.getItem("email");
    var myView = "Find your English Level";
    var ext1 = "https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/content";
    var ext2 = "Find your English Level";
    sendStatement(myView, name, email, ext1, ext2);
});



function sendStatement(m, n, e, ext1, ext2) {
    //var stmt = {"actor" : {"mbox" : "mailto:user@example.com"},
    var stmt = {"actor": {
            "mbox": ("mailto:" + e),
            "name": n
        },

        "verb": {"id": "http://adlnet.gov/expapi/verbs/accessed",
            "display": {"en-US": "accessed"}},
        "object": {"id": "https://www.syniverse.com/businessenglish",
            "definition": {

                /*"extensions": {
                 "https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/content": "Find your English Level"
                 },*/

                "extensions": {
                    ext1: ext2
                },

                "name": {
                    "en-US": m
                },

                "description": {
                    "en-US": "Business English"
                }
            },
        }};


    conf()
    ADL.XAPIWrapper.sendStatement(stmt, function (resp, obj) {
        ADL.XAPIWrapper.log("[" + obj.id + "]: " + resp.status + " - " + resp.statusText);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to use `ext1` as a variable for a key during object declaration, which you can't do.

This first one depends on the javascript you're using (browser or NodeJS), and is a more modern implementation.

`"extensions": {
  [ext1] : ext2
},`

https://jsfiddle.net/ak9L40n7/

Otherwise, after you define `stmt` you can set new key-value pairs this way with strings for the key

`stmt[ext1] = ext2`